Compiled lambda expression leading to new delegate allocations, whereas non-expression version does not
This compiled expression tree...
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
var innerParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Action<int>));
var inner = Expression.Lambda(innerParam.Type, Expression.Block(), "test", new[] { param });
var outer = Expression.Lambda<Action<int>>(Expression.Block(new[] { innerParam }, Expression.Assign(innerParam, inner), Expression.Invoke(innerParam, param)), param).Compile();

Appears to lead to the creation of a new delegate on every single invocation of outer - observable if eg setting a breakpoint in Delegate.CreateDelegateNoSecurityCheck.
In contrast, the non-expression based equivalent of this function
Action<int> outer = x =>
{
  Action<int> innerParam = _ => { };
  innerParam(x);
};

does not appear to do this; repeated invocations of outer do not need to any new delegate allocations.
I struggle do understand why. Is this intended? Is there any nifty trick to have the expression-based version's delegates cached?

For context: This came up when using an external Deserialization library that seemed to allocate an unreasonable amount of memory through Delegate creation in our process. In effect, it does something very similar - it creates deserializers via Expression trees, and assigns delegates to local variables to support recursive & circular deserialization.

If a lambda expression doesn't refer to any instance member, the delegate object will be cached: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAExAagD4AEBMBGAsAKHQGYACLEgYRIG8CT6S6GAHAJygDcIAXAUxNjcSATwDcTehLKl0AFhIBZABQBKGlIaN8mzemyYAPIIB8AmDF6sSAXhIB9G6b0BOJcJXjtO+nsMmzFqyYNvaONAC+nprhBOFAA=

@shingo Thanks, that lines up with my understanding in terms of capturing closures - though the expression based versions are also non capturing, so still not quite clear to me why those would not be cached


I struggle do understand why. Is this intended? Is there any nifty
trick to have the expression-based version's delegates cached?

It's because you don't explicitly cache the result of the inner delegate expression compilation.
In the case with the non-expresion based solution  the outerLambda is actually turned into a class with a field that can hold onto the innerLambda when the class is instantiated. Then calls to outer will be instance method invocations that make use of already created action delegate in the field:
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0
{
    public Action<int> inner;

    internal void <Main>b__1(int x)
    {
        Action<int> innerParam = inner;
        innerParam(x);
    }
}

Fortunately, if we make use of Expression.Constant we can have the same functionality with expressions.
Looking at what Compile does in the source code - it creates a Delegate at the end by calling this method:
private Delegate CreateDelegate() {
    Debug.Assert(_method is DynamicMethod);

    return _method.CreateDelegate(_lambda.Type, new Closure(_boundConstants.ToArray(), null));
}

This Closure instance will serve as the object Target of the Action<int> outer Delegate. That way the delegate can pass it as argument when invoking the actual compiled outer method:
Void lambda_method205(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, Int32)

If we have a look at Closure's source code we see that it has:
/// <summary>
/// Represents the non-trivial constants and locally executable expressions that are referenced by a dynamically generated method.
/// </summary>
public readonly object[] Constants;

which is populated by VariableBinder.VisitConstant during the traversing stage before the actual compilation of the delegate:
...
// Constants that can be emitted into IL don't need to be stored on
// the delegate
if (ILGen.CanEmitConstant(node.Value, node.Type)) {
    return node;
}

_constants.Peek().AddReference(node.Value!, node.Type);
...

So to modify the original example (with testing code credits to the other answer by Guru Stron) we would have:
static void Main() {
    var outerOriginal = CreateOuter(useConstantExpression: false);

    //outerOriginal.Target.Dump();
    MeasureAllocationsForInvocations(outerOriginal); // 8168 on my pc
    var outerWithConstantExpression = CreateOuter(useConstantExpression: true);
    // the Target of the delegate has the cached value of the inner Action<int>
    ////outerWithConstantExpression.Dump();
    //outerWithConstantExpression.Dump();

    MeasureAllocationsForInvocations(outerWithConstantExpression); // 0

    dynamic del = outerWithConstantExpression;
    // del.Target is Closure (using dynamic because I cannot reference the type even though it's public.. would edit if somebody assists)
    Console.WriteLine(del.Target.Constants[0].Method.ToString());
    // Void lambda_method204(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, Int32)
    Console.WriteLine(del.Method.ToString());
    //Void lambda_method205(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, Int32)
}



static void MeasureAllocationsForInvocations(Action<int> action) {
    var totalAllocatedBytes = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        action(1);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes() - totalAllocatedBytes);
}

static Action<int> CreateOuter(bool useConstantExpression, bool useConsoleWriteLineInnerBody = false) {

    var intParamInnerAndOuter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));

    var innerBlock = Expression.Block();
    // for debugging
    if (useConsoleWriteLineInnerBody) {
        MethodInfo writeLineMethod = typeof(Console).GetMethod("Write",
              new Type[] { typeof(int) });
        var writeLineCall = Expression.Call(writeLineMethod, intParamInnerAndOuter);
        innerBlock = Expression.Block(writeLineCall);
    }

    var innerParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Action<int>));
    var inner = Expression.Lambda(innerParam.Type,
        innerBlock, intParamInnerAndOuter);

    Expression expressionAssignment = useConstantExpression ?
        Expression.Constant(inner.Compile()) : inner;

    var outerBlock = Expression.Block(
       new[] { innerParam }, // Action<int> a;
     Expression.Assign(innerParam, expressionAssignment), 
     // a = closureParam.Constants[0]
     // or
     // a = new Action<int>(innerExpressionCompiledMethod)
     Expression.Invoke(innerParam, intParamInnerAndOuter)); // a(intParam);

    var outerExpression = Expression.Lambda<Action<int>>(outerBlock,
        intParamInnerAndOuter);

    var outer = outerExpression.Compile();
    // if constant it will inside do -> new Closure(new object[]{inner.Compile});
    return outer;
}

The only difference is in:
Expression expressionAssignment = useConstantExpression ?
        Expression.Constant(inner.Compile()) : inner;

This assignment to the local variable in the outer expression either uses the "cached" compiled delegate from closureParam.Constants[0] or will create each time new delegate based on the inner expression.
In the testing code (for my pc) the memory allocated is 8168 bytes for the original case and 0 for the second that relies on Expression.Constant

Hmm, my understanding was that Expression.Compile() effectively compiles into a DynamicAssembly -> DynamicModule -> DynamicType -> DynamicMethod ? Wouldn't it just be possible to add the cached state to the dynamic type here?

I wanted to address a possible misunderstanding that there's no "capturing" going on in the non-expression case. There is. Maybe it would be, but why would this be the default for Expression.Assign compared to the less-assuming non-caching behavior.

Oh, right you are - I've modified the non-expression version. That should now be equivalent to the expression version, and both be non-capturing I think

@Bogey so testing the non-expression version will be the same now, right? The decompiled code for the modified non-expression is: Action<int> innerParam = <>9__4_1 ?? (<>9__4_1 = new Action<int>(<>9.<Main>b__4_1));  innerParam(x); So new allocation in each invocation.

which I think answers the original question. For the "trick part", the other answer presents a good solution.

Maybe I'm missing something stupid now, but - your very pasted snipped from sharplab to me does suggest the delegate is being cached rather than recreated anew each time? <>9__4_1 is a static member that holds the function, and is only assigned once if null, otherwise being re-used. Which would tie up with this version being cached, whereas the expression-based version sadly is not

there is nothing cached with new in the method body of outer. It's not csharplab, but ILSpy, although same can be observed with the former - link -> compare it with your initial version where the field is reused.

and btw editing your question in this way completely misreps the title Compiled lambda expression leading to new delegate allocations, whereas non-expression version does not as it no longer leads to any difference...

Thanks @Ivan - I'm probably completely obtuse now I'm still not sure I understand. The current version has two static fields, both only ever assigned once if not null - everything is cached, whereas ...

... my pre-edit version allocates a new<>c__DisplayClass0_0() every call, i.e. not cached. So in my mind, the question is correct as it stands - the current, post-edit non-expression code uses all cached lambdas? Where do you see any non cached invocations there?

@Bogey my bad Bogey, must have been late when I commented. I was focusing on the new()... You are correct about the static fields. No need to modify the question. And I don't need to modify my answer cause the compiler uses classes this time with static fields instead of instance fields in the first version to cache the delegate. When I've look at Lambda.Combile code we just compile to Methods, not Types, so it's really not possible to cache. Maybe if you combined some Reflection.Emit to simulate the c# compiler's behavior, but I believe it's becoming too complex.

@Bogey I dug a bit deeper into the source code - seems that I wasn't aware of a handy Closure class that does the trick you wanted. No need for Expression.Call or getting the method as the other asnwer. We just do Expression.Invoke

One of the options here is to compile the inner lambda and call it:
var compile = inner.Compile();
var method = compile.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(Action<int>.Invoke));

var outerExpression = Expression.Lambda<Action<int>>(
    Expression.Block(
        new[] { innerParam },
        Expression.Assign(innerParam, Expression.Constant(compile)),
        Expression.Call(innerParam, method, param))
    , param);

var outer = outerExpression.Compile();

var totalAllocatedBytes = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000_000; i++)
{
    outer(1);
}

Console.WriteLine(GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes() - totalAllocatedBytes);

Which should be a complete analogue of the second snippet.

Thanks! I thought about that too, and while I think it might be a great solution for some cases, it probably wouldn't work for the underlying use case here (deserialization) - that needs to support self-references and circular references. The original code assigns each deserializer to a local variable so it can fake recursive calls that way - it might be hard if not impossible to find an approach where each deserialization lambda could be compiled in isolation of all others

@Bogey Arguably it would not be that impossible in general case - move this logic outside the expression trees compilation. Basically maintain a dictionary of a type -> deserializer and search/use one from there. You can use this approach for every type or deserialize "simple" ones in-place and perform look up only for complex ones.
